# Use RxJS pipe() to turn array into stream of asynchronous values in Angular

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs-pipeable-operators

```js
type Movie = {id: string};
type FullMovie = {id: string, picture: string};
```

I have a url that returns an array of type `Movie`:

```js
http.get(url).subscribe(res: Movie[])
```

I use `http.get(movie.id)` for **each** movie in the array returning a `FullMovie`:

```js
http.get(movie.id).subscribe(res: FullMovie)
```

so in essence I want to create a method that returns a stream of FullMovie objects, as the requests resolve: `getAll = (url): Observable<FullMovie>`

```js
getAll = (url): Observable<FullMovie> => {
  return http.get(url)
    //must pipe the array into a stream of FullMovies but not a stream of FullMovie Observables. I don't want to subscribe to each of the returned FullMovies
    //something like
   .pipe(//map(array => array.forEach(movie => return http.get(movie.id))))
}
```

At the moment I have the following solution that works but I want to a more concise solution:

```js
 private getFull = (queryGroup: string): Observable<TMDBMovie> =>
    new Observable<TMDBMovie>((observer) => {
      //get movie array
      this.httpGet(queryGroup).subscribe((movies) => {
        var j = 0;

        if (movies.length === 0) return observer.complete();

        //loop through elements
        movies.forEach(movie => {
          this.getById(movie.id).subscribe(
            (res) => complete(observer.next(res)),
            (error) => complete()
          );
        });
          
        }

        const complete = (arg: any = 0) => {
          if (++j === len) observer.complete();
        };
      });
    });
```

##### EDIT:

This works

```js
newGetFull = (queryGroup: string) =>
    this.httpGet(queryGroup)
      .pipe(concatMap((arr) => from(arr)))
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((movie) => this.getById(movie.id).pipe(catchError(() => of())))
      );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try something along these lines

```
getAll = (url): Observable<FullMovie> => {
  return http.get(url)
   .pipe(
      // turn the array Movie[] into a stream of Movie, i.e. an Obsevable<Movie>
      concatMap(arrayOfMovies => from(arrayOfMovies)),
      // then use mergeMap to "flatten" the various Obaservable<FullMovie> that you get calling http.get(movie.id)
      // in other words, with mergeMap, you turn a stream of Observables into a stream of the results returned when each Observable is resolved
      mergeMap(movie => http.get(movie.id))
   )
}
```

Consider that using `mergeMap` as above you do not have guarantee that the final stream will have the same order as the array of `Movie`s you get from the first call. This is because each `http.get(movie.id)` can take different time to return and therefore the order is not guaranteed.

If you need to guarantee the order, use `concatMap` rather than `mergeMap` (actually `concatMap` is `mergeMap` with concurrency set to 1).

If you want all the `http.get(movie.id)` to complete before returning the result, then use `forkJoin` rather than `mergeMap` like this

```
getAll = (url): Observable<FullMovie> => {
  return http.get(url)
   .pipe(
      // turn the array Movie[] into an array of Observable<Movie>
      map(arrayOfMovies => arrayOfMovies.map(movie => http.get(movie.id))),
      // then use forkJoin to resolve all the Observables in parallel
      concatMap(arrayOfObservables => forkJoin(arrayOfObservables))
   ).subscribe(
      arrayOfFullMovies => {
        // the result notified by forkJoin is an array of FullMovie objects
      }
   )
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly thanks! Just one more thing, If one of the http requests returns a 404 error the whole Observable stops, where do I use `catchError()` so it will continue since the code in my edit doesn't work in the right way?

Comment: Never mind I added it in the correct place thanks